# How to mock a file with no read permission in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

How to modify the following code such that the test is passed??

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock


def read_file(file_name):
    '''
        returns: tuple(error_code, data)
                 error_code = 1: file found, data will be read and returned.
                 error_code = 2: file not found, data is None.
                 error_code = 3: file found by cannot read it.
    '''
    try:
        with open(file_name) as fh:
            data = fh.read()
        return 1, data
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return 2, None
    except PermissionError:
        return 3, None


class TestReadFile(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('builtins.open', mock.mock_open(read_data=b''))
    def test_file_permission(self):
        err_code, data = read_file('file_name')
        assertEqual(err_code, 3)
```

I tried reading from this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic you've used in the program is correct, but the problem is you've used the wrong identifiers at places:

1) `unittest` doesn't have a class `Test`, it has [`TestCase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)

2) The function you want to test is named `read_file()`, but when calling it, you are instead calling `file_read()`

3) The keyword argument to `mock.mock_open()` is not `data`, but [`read_data`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.mock_open).

Here is the code with the suggested changes:

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock


def read_file(file_name):
    '''
        returns: tuple(error_code, data)
                 error_code = 1: file found, data will be read and returned.
                 error_code = 2: file not found, data is None.
                 error_code = 3: file found by cannot read it.
    '''
    try:
        with open(file_name) as fh:
            data = fh.read()
        return 1, data
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return 2, None
    except PermissionError:
        return 3, None


class TestReadFile(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('builtins.open', mock.mock_open(read_data=''))
    def test_file_permission(self):
        err_code, data = read_file('file_name')
        assertEqual(err_code, 3)
```